# Why is Gradle Build Failing Even after including the dependencies?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to follow the Spring guide for Gradle (http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/). As per the guide I added following to manage the dependency in the project.

```
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies {
        compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    }
```

Even after doing this, the build is getting failed

```
PS C:\Users\PMath\repositories\gradle> gradle build
:compileJava
C:\Users\PMath\repositories\gradle\src\main\java\hello\HelloWorld.java:3: error: package org.joda.time does not exis
t
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
                    ^
C:\Users\PMath\repositories\gradle\src\main\java\hello\HelloWorld.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
        ^
  symbol:   class LocalTime
  location: class HelloWorld
C:\Users\PMath\repositories\gradle\src\main\java\hello\HelloWorld.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class LocalTime
  location: class HelloWorld
3 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: I checked the Maven Repository, I see the dependency there: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|joda-time|joda-time|2.3|jar

Comment: Hard to say without more information (e.g. full build script). Try `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency joda` and check the output. Also try `gradle build --refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: The build file is the complete build file that I currently have.

Comment: gradle build --refresh-dependencies worked for me.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Git Clone http://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

This has already have running program. Just review and compare.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same tutorial and had the same issue.

This is happening because we forgot to add the next lines:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral() 
}
```

To the build.gradle file, just after the `apply plugin: 'java'`.
In the tutorial they mention that we need to add it, but they are not very clear where to.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the version, e.g. 2.2 to 2.9 (current version)